# Bash echo with an $ character outside the string

Tags: linux, bash, echo

Can anyone explain what is the difference between

```
echo $"Starting $CMD"
```

and

```
echo "String $CMD"
```

They seem to look the same.

Answer (score 6):

Look up the `QUOTING` section of the `bash` man page:

> Words of the form `$'string'` are treated specially.  The word  expands  to
>   string,  with  backslash- escaped  characters  replaced  as  specified by the
>   ANSI C standard.  Backslash escape sequences, if present, are decoded as
>   follows:
>
> - \a     alert (bell)
> - \b     backspace
> - \e     an escape character
> - \f     form feed
> - \n     new line
> - \r     carriage return
> - \t     horizontal tab
> - \v     vertical tab
> - \     backslash
> - \'     single quote
> - \nnn   the eight-bit character whose value is the octal value nnn (one to three digits)
> - \xHH   the eight-bit character whose value is the hexadecimal value HH (one or two  hex  digits)
> - \cx    a control-x character
>
> The expanded result is single-quoted, as if the dollar sign had not been present.

And note the follow description double quoted strings preceded by `$` (`$"string"`):

> A  double-quoted string preceded by a dollar sign ($) will cause the string
>   to be translated according to the current locale.  If the current locale is C
>   or POSIX, the dollar sign is ignored.  If the string is translated and
>   replaced, the replacement is double-quoted.

Comment: It's unfortunate that the man page doesn't leave the actual symbol `$"` somewhere near that so it can be found with a sane search.

Comment: It does, actually, down near the `extquote` option, which is how I knew to look for `$''`.  But yeah, it could be a lot more obvious.

Comment: Lucky the string `$'` occurred in the QUOTING section, then!

Comment: +1 great catch. I didn't think anyone else noticed this in the manpage.

Answer (score 4):

`$""` is a form of quoting that is used for language translation. If you invoke bash with the `-D` flag it will print out all such strings. When the locale is `C` or `POSIX`, this form of quotation doesn't do anything.

These strings are used by `gettext` to look up appropriate translations. For example, if your script has the string `$"Hello, World"` and you have properly installed MO files for translating that string into, say, French, you could execute your script this way:

```
LANGUAGE=fr_FR ./yourscript
```

and expect all instances of `$"Hello, World"` to be output as *Bonjour, Tout le Monde* (assuming that is what is actually in your translation file).

Translation is not magic or automatic, so [you must provide the translation engine with whatever translation strings it doesn't already have](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/098#Translate_the_strings).

(PS - the guide I linked to does mention [this security bug](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/bash.html), but you may miss it if you skim, so I highlight it again here.)

Comment: Could you give me some samples ?

Comment: Excuse me, `LANGUAGE=fr_FR ./myscrip.sh` will print `Hello, world`. Does it need to do some configuration for my Linux ?