# How can fix UTF-8 string usage in bash?

Tags: python, linux, bash, encoding, utf-8

I have a **bash** script what contains several **utf-8** string contained variables. These variables are used as parameters of a bash function in the sctript, what calls a `cp` and a `python` script with this parameters.

**This script runs properly on my machine, but can not work on another one.** I tried to debug with `set -x` and other stuffs, but I can not find the root cause, only this difference.

## There is a minimalized example - like Plunker for JS ;)

1. I have the following `test.sh`

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   set -x

   function aaa() {
       echo "$1"
   }
   echo 'öüóőúéáűíÖÜÓŐÚÉÁŰÍ'
   aaa 'öüóőúéáűíÖÜÓŐÚÉÁŰÍ'
   ```
2. I copy to my two hosts
3. The good shows the following:

   ```
   + echo öüóőúéáűíÖÜÓŐÚÉÁŰÍ
   öüóőúéáűíÖÜÓŐÚÉÁŰÍ
   + aaa öüóőúéáűíÖÜÓŐÚÉÁŰÍ
   + echo öüóőúéáűíÖÜÓŐÚÉÁŰÍ
   öüóőúéáűíÖÜÓŐÚÉÁŰÍ
   ```
4. However the bad shows this:

   ```
   + echo $'\303\266\303\274\303\263\305\221\303\272\303\251\303\241\305\261\303\255\303\226\303\234\303\223\305\220\303\232\303\211\303\201\305\260\303\215'
   öüóőúéáűíÖÜÓŐÚÉÁŰÍ
   + aaa $'\303\266\303\274\303\263\305\221\303\272\303\251\303\241\305\261\303\255\303\226\303\234\303\223\305\220\303\232\303\211\303\201\305\260\303\215'
   + echo $'\303\266\303\274\303\263\305\221\303\272\303\251\303\241\305\261\303\255\303\226\303\234\303\223\305\220\303\232\303\211\303\201\305\260\303\215'
   öüóőúéáűíÖÜÓŐÚÉÁŰÍ
   ```

---

## Here is some details for debugging:

The good working machine is a **Ubuntu Trusty** with `bash=4.2-2ubuntu2.6`, and the bad working machine is a **Ubuntu Precise** with `bash=4.3-7ubuntu1.5`.

The `locale`s are identical in both machines:

```
$ locale                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=POSIX
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

---

## Updates

- I was wrong with the `cp`, sorry.
- *I thought, the **python** exception is not related in this case, because the it was broken in **bash***. This backtrace can help anything?

  ```
  + /tmp/callrecord-renamer.py --skip --contacts $'/var/datastore/T\303\274nci/Rendszer/DropboxClone/contacts.ini' $'/var/datastore/T\303\274nci/DropboxClone/H\303\215V\303\201SFELV\303\211TELEK'
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/tmp/callrecord-renamer.py", line 316, in <module>
      main()
    File "/tmp/callrecord-renamer.py", line 312, in main
      FileManager(args.recording_path, contacts_path, args.no_change, args.skip_errors).update_files_in_directory()
    File "/tmp/callrecord-renamer.py", line 87, in update_files_in_directory
      self.contacts.load()
    File "/tmp/callrecord-renamer.py", line 56, in load
      self.database.read(self.file_path)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.2/configparser.py", line 689, in read
      self._read(fp, filename)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.2/configparser.py", line 994, in _read
      for lineno, line in enumerate(fp, start=1):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.2/codecs.py", line 300, in decode
      (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
  UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 3176: invalid start byte
  ```

*For more details, you can check this file on: https://github.com/andras-tim/callrecord-renamer/blob/master/callrecord-renamer.py*

## Update2

I have checked: this error caused independently from **bash** code. The **.ini** file encoding was bad... *Sorry for all debugger helpers!*

Comment: I'm not sure that you actually have a problem. The output is correct in both cases; you are just getting a different (but valid) representation in the debugging output on the "bad" host.

Comment: I have found this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11838597/bash-echo-with-an-character-outside-the-string  - but can't solve my problem... :(

Comment: @chepner the ``cp`` can not find the source path, however this is existing.

Comment: If you are having a problem with `cp` then *show us* the problem with `cp` and not some *other problem entirely*.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a shell issue, but a problem with `cp` on the bad host in dealing with a UTF-8 encoded string. The bad host is just showing the raw UTF-8 stream, rather than displaying the encoded Unicode characters. The data is the same on both machines (`\303\266`, for example, is in octal. The two bytes are 0xC3 and 0xB6, which is the UTF-8 encoding for U+00F6, ö.

Comment: I was bad with ``cp``, sorry. However, there was remaining this ``python`` problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing the xtrace debugging output of `set -x`. You can not and should not expect bash's xtrace output to be in a certain format. If you want a specific format, you need to produce it yourself.

If you look at the non-debug output your script, it's identical on both machines.

Comment: I'm debugging **bash** codes several years ago, but I can't see this escaping from ``set -x`` until now. - I'm blaming the encoding, because now, I have checked on a third machine (this was Precise too), where this script was worked.